# trying to remove duplicate date from multiple csv_files

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

I'm trying to remove any duplicate data from some csv data but my code that does this is nilling all the rows and I don't know why.
It figures out if it's a duplicate by checking if multiple fields from both match and then only if `.all` of them are true will it return true and thus delete the row but for some reason it' nilling everything regardless of the results (`true` or `false`).

Right, I forgot to mention, `csv_data` is an array with multiple csv_files read and pushed into it.
Also, the Duplication check is the columns of one row against the columns of another row in another table.

```
csv_data.each_with_index do |table,table_id|
    table.each do |row|
      csv_data.each_with_index do |compair_table,compair_table_id|
        compair_table.delete_if do |compair_row|
          if compair_table_id == table_id
            false
          else
            if(columns.all? do |field|
              row[field] == compair_row[field]
            end)
              true
            else
              false
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

What am I doing wrong? OR should I be trying a different approach completely?

Comment: How is `columns` defined?

Comment: How big is the CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

What you call `table` is actually a `row`, what you call a `row` is actually a `cell`, and `field` is actually a character inside this `cell`.

You're not comparing whole rows, you're comparing cells. If a cell appears more than twice anywhere in the CSV, it will get deleted.

With :

```
csv_data = CSV.parse("a,b,c\nd,e,f\na,b,c\ng,h,i\nd,h,c\nx,a,z")
columns = [0,1,2]
```

You get

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], [], ["g", "h", "i"], [], ["x", "z"]]
```

## Solution

You could just use [`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block, and apply it on rows. This example will delete any row that has the same first 2 cells than a previous row :

```
require 'csv'

csv_data = CSV.parse("a,b,c\nd,e,f\na,b,c\ng,h,i\nd,h,c\na,b,z")

columns = [0, 1]
unique_rows = csv_data.uniq! { |x| x.values_at(*columns) }
p unique_rows
#=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"], ["d", "h", "c"]]
```

Note that `unique_rows` is an Array now.

## Multiple tables

If you want unique rows across multiple tables, you could just join all the rows first :

```
all_rows = csv_tables.flatten_map{|table| table.to_a}
```

Comment: Umm oops, I should have mentioned that csv_data is an array with multiple csv file's pushed into it. 100% on me. Also, the duplication is from one csv table against another, there is no duplication within each table.

Comment: So, what should be the logic with multiple tables? Do you want unique rows across all tables, or just unique rows for each table?

Comment: unique across all tables, the reason I can't merge them is that ... hmm I could just join them first and then do a unique on the whole merged table...

Comment: Whilst this wasn't the solution to the actual problem (completly unrelated to this code) I'm going to tick this as it gave me a better solution.